# How Can I Provide 2 Ways to Search Index in Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I'm trying to create search with 2 ways. I did one of them (by Category) but i want to also search products by their name. I created search button in my project. But when i'm trying to searching with name, it brings me all products.

Image is showing my web-site. When i clicked to all products, fruits, phones, laptops or shirts it brings me only that category. This works well. But i have problem in search by string.

[image]

This is my controller code.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string categorySlug = "", int p = 1, string searchString=null)
    {

        //ViewBag yerine Model'da ProductIndex'de bunları tanımla
        int pageSize = 3;
        ViewBag.PageNumber = p;
        ViewBag.PageRange = pageSize;
        ViewBag.CategorySlug = categorySlug;

        if (categorySlug == "")
        {
            ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)_context.Products.Count() / pageSize);

            return View(await _context.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).Skip((p - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync());
        }

        Category category = await _context.Categories.Where(c => c.Slug == categorySlug).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (category == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");

        var productsByCategory = _context.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryId == category.Id);
        ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)productsByCategory.Count() / pageSize);

        return View(await productsByCategory.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).Skip((p - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync());

        var products = from m in _context.Products
                       select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            products = products.Where(s => s.Name!.Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(await products.ToListAsync());


    }
```

This is my View code for searching by string:

```
                <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index" method="get">
                    <p>
                        Search: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
                    </p>
                </form>
```

Comment: What do you see when debugging? Does `searchString` in your controller action actually contain the value you expect?

Comment: @Xerillio Actually i can't put breakpoint searchString. Controller doesn't contain right value.